# Nested FOR loops: readability & performance

Tags: c#, performance, loops, for-loop

I understand nested FOR loops. I understand what they do, and how they do it. But my problem is that they seem horribly unreadable to me.

Take this example:

```
for (int i = 0, y = 0; y <= ySize; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++, i++) {
        vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y);
    }
}
```

Now, this loop is pretty straightforward. It's just an x/y "2 dimensional" loop. But as I add more and more "dimensions" to this nested loop, **is there a way to make the code not a horrible mess of nests within nests and stupid amounts of backtracing counter variables (i, x, y, z, etc.)?**

Also, does additional nesting affect performance in a linear way, or do additonal FORs make things more and more inefficient as you nest more of them?

Comment: I believe this questions is more like http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Alex when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Regarding performance, usually most time is spent by the body of the innermost loop. That loop does not usually take any more time per iteration just because it is at the bottom of a nested stack of loops. It is only a performance problem if it does more iterations than it needs to. Regarding readability, the structure of your problem determines how deep your nesting needs to be. You can split them into separate functions with descriptive names, to help you keep track.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that the issue you have here is less the nested `for` loops, and more an unusual use of variables within the loops.

Newlines before the opening braces can help with readability too (although this is [subjective](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/should-curly-braces-appear-on-their-own-line)).

How about this instead:

```
int i = 0;

for (int y = 0; y <= ySize; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
    {
        vertices[i++] = new Vector3(x, y);
    }
}
```

This approach should remain *relatively* readable for additional dimensions too (in this example I've moved the incrementing of `i` out to its own line, as suggested by *usr*).

```
int i = 0;

for (int y = 0; y <= ySize; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a <= aSize; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b <= bSize; b++)
            {
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y, a, b);

                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding performance, I would suggest focussing on making sure that the code is readable and understandable by a human first, and then measuring the run-time performance, possibly with a tool such as [RedGate ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

Comment: I'd even pull the i++ out of the assignment. It's like someone was trying to compress the code trying to save bytes.

Comment: Agreed. Have updated the second example to illustrate this.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that putting the opening curly brace on the same line as the for block is only readable in javascript - and no-one knows why.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner - Not quite true; having the opening curly brace on the same line as the block before it is known as [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) style, and was used in [The C Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language), hence its popularity. The style I've suggested (and prefer) is apparently known as [Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style).

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner aside from not being "only readable in JavaScript" and I really don't know anybody who has claimed this, JS does have an extra incentive to have the open brace at the same line - it prevents HORRIBLE bugs if you try to return an object - due to Automatic Semicolumn Insertion (ASI) if you have a `return` statement and a _newline_ following it, then it immediately returns, thus making the rest of the code unreachable. Thus if you thought you were returning the object literal on the next line...you aren't. If you place the curly brace on the same line, this is avoided.

Comment: @Vld Maybe I should have worn less of a straight face while saying that. :-)  There you go. But everyone I work with - all using C# and javascipt - has reported the same phenomenon; distinct stylistic norms in javascript look horrible in C#, and vice versa. Despite being viewed in the same editor. (And no-one knows why!)

Comment: Style is clearly an Opine and shut Case.

Comment: `(int b = 0; b <= xSize; b++)` that looks like a bug

Comment: Thanks @mikeTheLiar - corrected.

Answer (score 12):

The usual solution is to refactor into methods which contain one or two for loops, and keep refactoring until each method is clear and not too large.

Another solution to stop the indenting, and to separate the loop-resulting-data from the applying-logic, is to use Linq.

```
int i = 0;
var coordinates = from y in Enumerable.Range(0, ySize + 1)
                  from x in Enumerable.Range(0, xSize + 1)
                  select new { x, y, i = i++ };

foreach (var coordinate in coordinates) {
    vertices[coordinate.i] = new Vector3(coordinate.x, coordinate.y);
}
```

This is only if the `vertices` array is already declared. If you can just create a new array, then you can do simply this:

```
var vertices = (from y in Enumerable.Range(0, ySize + 1)
                from x in Enumerable.Range(0, xSize + 1)
                select new Vector3(coordinate.x, coordinate.y)
               ).ToArray();
```

Comment: You can remove the nasty side effect i++ from the query by using the `Select((item, index) => ...)` overload. It creates the indexes for you.

Comment: @usr That won't work since the `i` will keep increasing for a new value of `y`.

Comment: @usr it can of course be refactored into `i = ((y - 1) * ySize) + x);` but I didn't wanted to change the logic that is in the question.

Comment: What I meant was `coords.Select((item, index) => ...)`. Add the index after computing the x, y values.

Comment: You mentioned refactoring, and you mentioned LINQ.  I'm (almost) tempted to create another account just to be able to give you the two upvotes you deserve!

Comment: The linq approach is like 7x slower here and it is questionable if it is easier to read.

Answer (score 9):

```
var vertices =
 (from y in Enumerable.Range(0, ySize)
  from x in Enumerable.Range(0, xSize)
  select new Vector3(x, y)).ToList();
```

Loops are overused. Most loops can be expressed as queries. That makes them easier to write and maintain and it makes them expressions as opposed to statements which are easier to move around.

Performance is much worse, like 3-10x here. Whether that matters to your specific case depends on how much time is spent here and what your performance goals are.

Comment: Well, what if we don't want to be THAT high level. Of course it's a good alternative, LINQ. But not everyone is forced to do it, and if performance is worse it's no longer a good alternative.

Comment: You are implying that all LINQ queries are not good because they are pretty much all slower than a manual loop. That can't be right...

Comment: Can you back up the claim that the performance is 3-10x worse?

Comment: @usr Well using LINQ queries versus manual loops is something to balance between performance and readability. And believe me, performance can actually be an issue in some cases, more than in others. A loop that runs once is alright. A loop that turns a 1s calculation into a 1m calculation is not good.

Comment: And then you have to write in C without the luxury of LINQ

Comment: @Maarten that's my experience with such loops from quite a number of perf tests. LINQ is quite a lot slower than a tight loop. For example, each outer iteration allocates a new `Enumerable.Range(0, xSize)`. That is expensive. Each item runs through I think 6 vcalls.

Comment: @usr - to mitigate this you could store the value returned from `Enumerable.Range(0, xSize)` in a separate variable, and then use that in the `from` statement.

Comment: @RichardEverett would need to materialize that into a list. That would work but it would destroy the expression nature of this because it requires a statement.

Answer (score 5):

a) Usually you will find that you're not going to need very deep nesting, so it won't be a problem.

b) You can make the nested loops into a separate method. <sub>(i.e. if you're nesting `d` in `c` in `b` in `a` - you can make a method that accepts `a` and `b` as parameters and does `c` and `d`. You can even let VS do this for you by selecting the `c` loop and clicking Edit->Refactor->Extract Method.)</sub>

As for performance - obviously more nesting means more iterations, but if you have them - you need them. Just changing a nested loop to be included in the original loop (and calculating where you are inside the "actual" code) will IMHO usually not help in any noticeable way.

Comment: Thank you for the Extract Method tip. I did not think of it in this context.

Answer (score 1):

An N-deep loop nest is likely to be **more** readable than any alternative expressible in C#.  Instead, consider the use of a higher-level language that has vector arithmetic as a primitive:  for instance, in [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html) the direct equivalent of your code is

```
xSize = 10
ySize = 20
vertices = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(0, xSize, xSize),
    np.linspace(0, ySize, ySize))
```

and the N-dimensional generalization is

```
sizes = [10, 20, 30, 40, 10] # as many array entries as you like
vertices = np.meshgrid(*(
    np.linspace(0, kSize, kSize)
    for kSize in sizes))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just messing around here, but how about padding out spaces so that the loop conditions line up?  Here is @Richard Everett's code reformatted a bit:

```
int i = 0;
for             (int y = 0; y <= ySize; y++) {
    for         (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++) {
        for     (int a = 0; a <= aSize; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b <= bSize; b++) {
                vertices[i++] = new Vector3(x, y, a, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```